# dynamic sql in stored procedure with column name as input parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have this stored procedure that accept a comlumn name as inptu parameter. The SELECT statement will select a column according to input parameter

```
create procedure getColumn (@whichColumn varchar)
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
    set @sql = 'SELECT [' + @whichColumn + ']' 
        + ' FROM myTable'
        + ' where ['+ @whichColumn + '] is not null'
        + ' and [' + @whichColumn + '] != '''' ' ;
    exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```

When I execute this stored procedure,

```
exec getColumn 'Apple';
```

the error says "Invalid column name 'A' " . 
I cannot see why it only gets the first character of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
create procedure getClumn (@whichColumn varchar)
```

to

```
create procedure getClumn (@whichColumn varchar(max))
```

because if you are not assign size of varchar at that time it consider only one character so it get only one character A and generate error.

Comment: Whoa let's not get carried away and go all the way to `VARCHAR(MAX)` my assumption is he probably needs less than 8,000 characters to accomplish this.

Comment: @Zane My assumption is hes never going to need more than 128 :)

Answer (score 7):

Check out your parameter declaration:

```
@whichColumn varchar
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.

So that's a single-letter `varchar`.  Try to specify a size:

```
@whichColumn varchar(50)
```

Or even better, use the system-defined type for object names:

```
@whichColumn sysname
```

Comment: ^^^^This is your answer. Always declare the length of your columns.

Comment: I thought it was 30 if no length has been mentioned :S

Comment: @M.Ali: That's true if you omit the length in `cast` and `convert`.  But in variable declarations, the default length is one.  You can [vote here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=244395) to fix the madness.

Comment: opss got it mixed. :) I have tried to vote but it wont let me will try it later.

Comment: /sigh the fact that this isn't the accepted answer is troubling.

Answer (score 3):

```
create procedure getColumn (@whichColumn nvarchar(128))   --<-- Maximum column name lenght
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max); 
    set @sql =   N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@whichColumn)+ N' FROM myTable'
               + N' where '+ QUOTENAME(@whichColumn) + N' is not null'
               + N' and ' + QUOTENAME(@whichColumn)  +  N' != '''' ' ;
    exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```

On a side note Using square brackets in you concatinating string isnt the same as using QUOTENAME function.

Comment: DO you care to leave a comment whoever has down voted ?

Comment: +1 to off balance. Not sure why you got the DV either.

Comment: Cheers Zane there are some numpties out there down voting for fun. I wish there was a system in place that every time some down voted unfairly it would -100 their reputation :S

Comment: M. Ali I did not know about TSQL keyword QUOTENAME until I read your suggested answer. It solved the issue I was having writing dynamic SQL to set a column name in an UPDATE stored procedure.  A bonus is it's cleaner to write and understand IMHO.